# ParametricNDSolveValue over a region

Tags: differential-equations, regions

I'm getting the following behavior I don't understand when using `ParametricNDSolveValue` over a region. You can reproduce the behavior considering Poisson's equation as shown below

The below works as I expect:

```
op = Laplacian[f[x, y], {x, y}];

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{b == op, 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == 0]}, 
  f[0.5, 0.5], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {b}];

Table[sol[b], {b, -10, 10, 5}]
```

With the result

```
{4.75, 2.875, 1., -0.875, -2.75}
```

Using the same code, but replacing the integration limits with a region:

```
sol2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{b == op, 
   DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == 0]}, 
  f[0.5, 0.5], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[], {b}];

Table[sol2[b], {b, -10, 10, 5}]
```

results in

```
{4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75, 4.75}
```

i.e., the result for the first call to sol2 repeated.

I can of course force the behavior I want (below) but it would be nice to understand why using a region gives different behavior!

```
sol3[b_] := 
 NDSolveValue[{b == op, DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == 0]}, 
  f[0.5, 0.5], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[]];

Table[sol3[\[Beta]], {\[Beta], -10, 10, 5}]

{4.75, 2.875, 1., -0.875, -2.75}
```

Thanks,

Jim

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: My guess is that it's a bug.  This also seems to reveal a bug: `sol2 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{b == op, DirichletCondition[f[x, y] == 1, x == 0]}, f[0.5, 0.5], {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[], {b}, Method -> {"ParametricCaching" -> None}]`.  No idea if they're connected since the option fails on `sol1` as well.